# Android Could not connect to database 08001

Tags: android, mysql

I try to connect MYSQL server with following code:

```
 conexionMysql = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://DBSERVER:1433/xTraining?user=sa&password=Phoenix14");
```

But always got the same error:

```
 I/---ERROR---: Could not create connection to database server.
 I/---ERROR---: 08001
 W/gralloc_ranchu: Gralloc pipe failed

              [ 11-16 11:22:08.532  3618: 3618 D/         ]
              HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb2910380, tid 3618


              [ 11-16 11:22:08.841  1509: 1534 D/         ]
              HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x966ff2c0, tid 1534
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you are using for providing the url is wrong.Do it like this:

```
conexionMysql = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://DBSERVER:1433/xTraining","sa","Phoenix14");
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Still got the same error.
I use the first code because i see here: [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html#connector-j-examples-connection-drivermanager)

Comment: is your connection url correct?It should be in this form:

Comment: "jdbc:mysql://hostname:port-number/Database name"

Comment: I check it and yes

Comment: have you provided mysql-connector.jar to your classpath?

Comment: I can see Android Studio dont add nothing more in classpath

Comment: In case you haven't added the jar,add it to your project like this: 1)Add a folder in your project named "Libs" and keep the jar file inside this folder.
2)In the "Project->Project" view, You will be able to see the jar file from android studio (you may not see it in the "Project->android" view). Right click on the jar file and select the option "Add as Library" and Click Ok.

Comment: And dont forget to include it in dependencies.You can find dependencies in gradle.build(Module:App).

Comment: When i do this i got a fatal error from Android Studio. I import the lib whit maven repository and now its working fine